# Extending generics in Swift?

Tags: generics, swift

I'm trying to extend `Array<T>` in Swift to add a function that calls `self.append`. The problem is that Swift won't seem to let me do that - when I try the following code:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func AppendObj<T>(obj: T) {
        //...
        self.append(obj);
    }
}
```

it says 'T' is not convertable to 'T,' which I assume means that the 'T' the underlying Array is using might be different than the T passed to `AppendObj`. It also won't allow me to use `extension Array<T>` ("use of undeclared type T").

Is it possible to extend & use generic structs/methods in Swift? Thanks!

Comment: If I may make a suggestion, don't call your method `AppendObj`. Instead, call it `appendObj`. Method names should begin with a lower case letter in Swift (and Obj-C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't specify generics for the function, it overrides the existing template. Just leave it out:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func AppendObj(obj: T) {
        //...
        self.append(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: That...makes perfect sense xD

Thanks!